# Reusing collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, architecture, uicollectionview

I have VC and a collectionView inside of it. All the code that manages collection view i've putted in extension to that VC. But now i need to use this collection view inside another different VC, and i dont want to copy/paste this extension. I've tried to subclass UICollectionView, but it doest not call delegate/datasource methods inside. Here is signature of my extension:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView)
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
```

and some private functions and properties. Where i should put all this methods, if i want to reuse them often?

Comment: there is another option to make a extension for these two classes and put these method in it.

Comment: Is there any examples of doing that? That's the most straightforward way to do this, but i have no idea how it should looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put all of this logic into a separate VC and reuse the VC, you aren't just trying to reuse the collection view.

So, wherever you need a 'copy' of this collection view you would actually be adding a child VC and adding the view from the VC as a subview.

Comment: So i need to add my collectionView in container view? At now, i've got just a UICollectionView inside my view

Comment: no, you would have an entirely new view controller, which can be a subclass of `UICollectionViewController` and you'd add it's view (a collection view) as a subview

Comment: I'm using storyboards, so i cant understand what do you want to say :( Can you explain the difference? My idea is that i create container view, then create UICOllectionVIewController, and link it with container view with embed segue.